# Maintaining proper CSS \ Javascript and using a Template Engine - a contradiction?

Tags: javascript, css, velocity, template-engine

A template engine (Velocity, FreeMaker, etc.) lets you, among other things, split up your HTML into re-usable chunks. E.g. you have a `<div>` showing an ad that appears on lots of places in your site - you can compose a file containing that `<div>` and its contents once (with Velocity: a 'myAd.vm' file), and load it up into whatever page necessary (with Velocity: apply `#parse('myAd.vm')`.

I like to think of these .vm files as functions, they get "invoked" (parsed) and spit out textual content. They can have "parameters" - in Velocity you can `#set( $myParam = 'foo' )` just before parsing the 'myAd.vm' file, and use that variable inside that file.

My question is: How does the proper way of defining CSS and Javascript in their own files fit in with that?

The 'myAd.vm' needs CSS styling, you can define that CSS in that file itself with a `<style>` tag - which will result in an HTML document with a style tag in its `<body>` - not in its `<head>`, and certainly not in a separate file.

Or, you could define the CSS that 'myAd.vm' needs in a separate 'myAd.css' file, and demand that whatever HTML document that parses 'myAd.vm' will have a `<LINK REL="StyleSheet" HREF="myAd.css" TYPE="text/css">` in its head tag. This is a problem since it makes things more complex and cumbersome, and - you may want to actually parse the 'myAd.vm' file depending on a conditional (in Velocity, for example, you could have `#if(someCondition) #parse('myAd.vm') #end`) - meaning you don't actually know in advance whether the head tag should link to that external CSS file.

Any thoughts?
Thanks.

Comment: Template engines add quite a bit of server overhead, and often disable or limit the browser's caching system. You need to consider whether having clean code is worth the performance tradeoff. For the projects I work on, we've chosen to use templating for HTML, but not for CSS and JavaScript since they're fairly simple. We split CSS and JavaScript into individual files to create some structure. You should use Safari/Chrome's network inspector to check your performance (pay attention to the latency part). We use the HTML template to determine which CSS/JavaScript files to include in the <head>

Comment: so if you have an HTML template you include in a page, you have one line in the page's head that loads up the CSS\JS for the template and another line in the page's body that loads up the actual template?

Comment: We have a series of templates that are used to render the content of the page, and we render this first. While these are processed, they append to an array of css/javascript files needed for the page. Then once they are processed, we embed it's html into a "main" template, which includes the `<head>` tag, the site navigation, and the footer. The main template generates whatever css/script tags are needed by the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most frameworks that ive used give you the ability to make some kind of function call that kind of acts as an include for a css or js file, these are then output in the head to external files. In many casses i actually run all these through a minifier so in the end there is only one css and one js file.

This way you can add to the asset stack from within view partials and put stuff directly in the head.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you, you define CSS in the view partial (= the template) and then cause it to appear in the document's head?

Comment: yeah so in a view partial you might see something like: `include_stylesheet('partial-name.css')` and then its added to the stack that gets output in the head tag.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org) (a component-based framework) allows you to add what it calls "Header contributions" ("renderHead" method now in Wicket 1.5) as a part of its page composition through inheritance system. This means that, although a page only defines a chunk of the total HTML to be rendered, it can still add something to the <head> of the whole document and therefore include <link> tags for your javascript and CSS files in their correct places.

As for non-component-based frameworks, the [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org) template engine (which can be used with Spring MVC), as a result of its "natural templating" ability, allows you to compose pages by including fragments from other pages (both in <head> and in <body>, which to some extent solves your issue), as opposed to the "inheritance-oriented" approach natural to composition frameworks like Sitemesh or Tiles.

Regards,
Daniel.